# System Data SqlClient SqlException

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server, ado.net

I have to execute an updating query :

```
 using (SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE  Test SET Testedpiece = Testedpiece + 1 and Rate = (Testedpiece  * 100) / Totalpiece  WHERE IDSuperlot = @super", connexion))
```

But i have this error  `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'and'.`

I don't know why this error appears and how can i fix it

1. What is the Sql Syntax error?
2. How can i fix it?

Comment: There's a strong hint in the error message itself: *"Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'and'."*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your sql command starts like this:

```
UPDATE  Test SET Testedpiece = Testedpiece + 1 and Rate = ...
```

change it to this:

```
UPDATE  Test SET Testedpiece = Testedpiece + 1, Rate = ...
```